# Outlook web addin issues

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook Web Addin using Fabric UI.I have run into couple of issues which are given as follows:

The following is my outlook web addin screen shot:

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is2eq.png): [image]

Issue #1 : I do not have access to addin title "My Test Outlook Web Addin" from within my code. I want to change the CSS properties of the title but I do not seem to have access. This title is defined in an XML file.

Issue #2: I have "Save" and "Cancel" buttons. In their call backs I need to perform some task and close the addin dialog. But I am not able to close the addin dialog. I can close the addin by clicking 'X' icon on the top, but not from within my code.

Issue #3, How to get file types icon with plane JS? (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/web/file-type-icons)

I am not using React or AngularJS. I am using Core fabric UI with plane JS.

Any help on these issues and on how to control properties of outlook web addin is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Issue #1: It is currently not possible to change the styling of the title bar. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

For Issue #2: You can use the [closeContainer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=outlook-js-preview#closecontainer--) to close the add-in task pane.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am not able to call closeContainer() method from my jS code. The available office object Office.context does not have this method, and Office.context.ui is not available.

Comment: I am not using React or AngularJS. I am using Core fabric UI with plane JS

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT,  I also need to know that how to get file types icons without using React or AngularJS.

Comment: Office.context.ui is available now for me. My reference was not correct.

Comment: So we trust that this issue been solved for you? If you're also facing a different issue, could you ask a separate question? It's easier for us to keep track of. Thanks!

Comment: Yes issue#2 is solved. Thanks. I will raise another question for file types icons

Comment: I have posted a new question for file types icon. Please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60107098/file-types-mime-types-issue-in-outlook-web-addin-using-fabric-ui