# File types (mime types) issue in Outlook web addin using Fabric UI

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an Outlook Web Addin using Fabric UI framework. Im using Fabric UI Core without React or AngularJS. I am facing an issue in getting File Types (MIME types) icons. Whatever references I found online for File types in Fabric UI are for React framework.

Is there a way to get file types in Fabric UI with plain Javascript without React? I found the following links where file types are available:

https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/item-types/16/csv.svg

https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/brand-icons/document/svg/pptx_16x1.svg

I can write a simple JS code to pass appropriate file extension in the above URL to load the intended file type icon. For example :

https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/brand-icons/document/svg/[file extension]_16x1.svg

Is it correct to get file types this way? Are these URLs reliable source for getting file types icon?

Any help is appreciated with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@uifabric/file-type-icons` is the current package containing the set of file type icon mappings. It includes a registration helper along with a few functions to derive a given extension to an image mapping.

`@uifabric/styling` contains the general icon helper `getIcon` to pull registered icons from any icon registrations.

I've made a codesandbox example here using vanilla JS:
https://codesandbox.io/s/uifabric-filetypeicons-example-yoyp6

...and a cleaner more interactive example in React:
https://codesandbox.io/s/file-type-icons-2s54c

The important steps are:

1. Call `initializeFileTypeIcons` to register file type icons in the icon registry.
2. Call `getIconProps({ extension: 'docx', size: 16 })` to get details on the iconName to map to.
3. Call `getIcon` to get the details of the icon, where you can access the url, which you can inject into raw HTML or use your framework of choice to render an img.

Note that the styling package has a peer dependency on React, so I needed to add it, but it is not being used here. This is something we could certainly improve on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David. Your code is written using React. But I am not using React. I am writing code in plain JS. I am using Fabric Core which does not require React or AngularJS. Can you please tell me that if it is possible to get icons without using React ?

Comment: I've made a separate codesandbox that does the above using vanilla js. Note that while I did need to add React as a peer dependency to make Parcel happy, it is not being used. Solution above edited to include this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/uifabric-filetypeicons-example-yoyp6

Comment: When I run the above index.js code in my visual studio 2019 asp.net core web project I get the following error : TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: @uifabric/file-type-icons

Comment: David, how to get the dependencies : uifabric/file-type-icons in visual studio 2019? Is installing via npm only option?

Comment: I haven't worked with asp.net core in a while. I believe you should be able to npm install things in that environment though; just not sure I can help with your environment situation. Found this: https://forums.asp.net/t/2145671.aspx?Best+way+of+using+npm+packages+in+asp+net+core

Comment: The initializeFileTypeIcons() call has code which makes React calls. So this code would not work without having React. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What, if I want to get the folder icon?

Comment: Ok I found my answer. If no extension is passed to `GetIconProps`, you can pass a `FileIconType` of `folder`, here is the source to understand the function better: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/file-type-icons/src/getFileTypeIconProps.ts#L51